# How separate unset json properties from null json properties in java and PATCH requests?

Tags: java, json, patch

Suppose I want to handle patch requests and write code like that:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}",
        method = RequestMethod.PATCH)
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
public SomeResponse updateType(@PathVariable String id,
                               @RequestBody ContactDto contact) throws Throwable {
    //extract parameters from contact 
}
```

So the problem is how recognize what parameters are set from patch requests? At first look it is obvious to write like this:

```
if (contact.getHobby() != null) {
    updateHobby(contact.getHobby());   
}
```

But what if I want to set `hobby` to null via json or delete it from current contact? So I pass a json string without `hobby` property and upper code does not work.
So the problem is - how separate properties that are set to null from those which are not set at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The body of a PATCH request should describe the changes to be made on the target entity.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789#section-2) You shouldn't pass the entity itself.

> With PATCH, however, the enclosed entity contains a set of
> instructions describing how a resource currently residing on the
> origin server should be modified to produce a new version.

For example, if you wanted to remove the hobby, you could pass some JSON like

```
{"removeHobby":true}
```

Your application would parse that and know it had to alter the entity by removing its hobby value.